# How to compare the trackingArea of NSEvent to see which trackingArea triggered the "theEvent"

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstrackingarea

So, I have this mouseEntered event that will make visible a label if I mouse enter a trackingArea. But, depending on which trackingArea was entered I want to set a custom String to the label.

The main question is: How do I get which trackingArea was entered.

This is my code:

```
-(void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
   if([theEvent trackingArea] isEqual: -- to my trackingArea --)
   {
       [self.label setStringValue:@"Test"];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the beginning of [Spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) to me..

I.e.: Checking in one view whether something was triggered by another view - I suppose you're attempting to implement some kind of online help system with some text to be displayed for various views/controls. In that case you might easily end up with a huge if-then-else block and dozens of views to check.

In any case I'd suggest to use a different approach and embrace [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) in your code:

**How about having the view that actually *owns* the tracking area send a notification with the string it wants somebody else to display?**

That way views don't need to know each other, no instance variables to set up to point to each other, etc. - just a notification somebody sends and somebody else will listen to.

Clean, maintainable, easily extensible.

Comment: No, this is part of the same view. I have two buttons, each with its own trackingArea, when I mouseEnter a trackingArea I want a label to display some text depending on what button I mouseEntered.